# How to convert a json array that have same dates but different times to another format of json array that group time and id attributes with same date?

Tags: php, json

I have a json array with ids, datetimes and soldout attributes that looks like below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2020-06-07 09:30:00",
        "fdate":"7 Jun",
        "soldout": true
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2020-06-07 17:00:00",
        "fdate":"7 Jun",
        "soldout": false
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "date": "2020-06-08 10:00:00",
        "fdate":"8 Jun",
        "soldout": false
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "date": "2020-06-08 18:30:00",
        "fdate":"8 Jun",
        "soldout": true
    }
]
```

I have a hard time to figure out to solve this problem.
I would like to group time(s), id and soldout attributes for a same date.
How do I convert the above json array to below json format in PHP:-

```
[
    {
        "date":"2020-06-07",
        "fdate": "7 Jun",
        "times": [
            {
                "id":2,
                "time": "9:30 am",
                "soldout: true
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "time": "5:00 pm",
                "soldout": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date":"2020-06-08",
        "fdate": "8 Jun",
        "times": [
            {
                "id":4,
                "time": "10:00 am",
                "soldout": false
            },
            {
                "id":5,
                "time": "6:30 pm",
                "soldout": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You can find my code here: https://rextester.com/KNGH26986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    $out = [];
    foreach($x as $x)
    {
        $date = strtotime($x['date']);
        $day = date('Y-m-d',$date);
        $time = date('h:i a', $date);
        if(!array_key_exists($x['fdate'],$out))
        {
            $out[$x['fdate']] = [
                'fdate' => $x['fdate'],
                'date'  => $day,
            ];
            $out[$x['fdate']]['times'][] = [
                'id' => $x['id'],
                'time'  => $time,
                'soldout' => $x['soldout']
            ];
        }
        else
        {
            $out[$x['fdate']]['times'][] = [
                'id' => $x['id'],
                'time'  => $time,
                'soldout' => $x['soldout']
            ];
        }
    }
    $res=[];
    foreach($out as $out)
    {
        $res[] = $out;
    }
    dd(json_encode($res));
```

Output will be

```
[
    {
        "date":"2020-06-07",
        "fdate": "7 Jun",
        "times": [
            {
                "id":2,
                "time": "9:30 am",
                "soldout": true
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "time": "5:00 pm",
                "soldout": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date":"2020-06-08",
        "fdate": "8 Jun",
        "times": [
            {
                "id":4,
                "time": "10:00 am",
                "soldout": false
            },
            {
                "id":5,
                "time": "6:30 pm",
                "soldout": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jithesh Jose for the solution. I made few changes on his solution by including the source of the json input and making sure it can run on an online editor. 
Here is the code :-

```
<?php

$json = '[{
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2020-06-07 09:30:00",
        "fdate": "7 Jun",
        "soldout": true
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2020-06-07 17:00:00",
        "fdate": "7 Jun",
        "soldout": false
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "date": "2020-06-08 10:00:00",
        "fdate": "8 Jun",
        "soldout": false
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "date": "2020-06-08 18:30:00",
        "fdate": "8 Jun",
        "soldout": true
    }]';
$db = json_decode($json);
$out = array();
foreach( $db as $x ){

    $date = strtotime($x->date);
    $day = date('Y-m-d',$date);
    $time = date('h:i a', $date);

    if(!array_key_exists($x->fdate,$out))
    {
      $out[$x->fdate] = [
       'fdate' => $x->fdate,
       'date'  => $day,
      ];

      $out[$x->fdate]['times'][] = [
       'id' => $x->id,
       'time'  => $time,
       'soldout' => $x->soldout
      ];     

    }else
    {
      $out[$x->fdate]['times'][] = [
       'id' => $x->id,
       'time'  => $time,
       'soldout' => $x->soldout
      ];
    }
}
$res=[];
foreach($out as $o)
{
 $res[] = $o;
}
echo json_encode($res);  
?>
```